# Ember.cli acceptance tests Could not find module

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have been trying to figure out why my integration tests aren't working for a few days now. Here is the travis log:

https://travis-ci.org/allistera/mileager.io-front

The error is:

Could not find module `ember-modal-dialog/initializers/add-modals-container` imported from `car-mileager-frontend/initializers/add-modals-container`

The only reference to add-modals-container that I can find is in a third party package ember-cli-materialise.

I also mock my API using ember-mock.

Kind of new to ember so not sure what further debugging I can do. The source code for the project is:

http://github.com/allistera/mileager.io-front

When I run

$ ember test

From my command line I get the same error...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you figure out what was wrong? I'm running into the same error: `...at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:6647: Could not find module 'ember-modal-dialog/initializers/add-modals-container'...`

Comment: No I didn't sorry, I ended up moving to using the compiled CSS version rather than the SASS one of materialise. I think the issue lies in the ember-cli-materialise package, but never had time to track it down.

Comment: I happened to figure this out, at least for my project, after leaving the comment above. I've posted the solution that worked for me below. Best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know... (this is a follow-up from my comment above-- I ran into the same issue).

The root cause of this issue is that PhantomJS 1.9.x doesn't support ES5, which is used in `ember-cli-materialize` (specifically, Function.prototype.bind). The symptom is that Ember acceptance tests will fail in Phantom, but pass in your browser, when running `ember test --server`. The solution is to upgrade your `phantom` binary to 2.0, or use the addon `ember-cli-es5-shim` in your Ember project.

There is a PR open here: https://github.com/mike-north/ember-cli-materialize/pull/237 to add a note about this to the `ember-cli-materialize` README.

For more background, check out the issue thread: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/2634

Hope that helps-- let me know if you happen to implement this solution, and if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Awesome thanks Max! Can move back to the SCSS version now.